# In R shiny, how to retain values in expanding input matrix when matrix is re-rendered?

Tags: r, matrix, shiny

The following MWE code has a reactivity chain where the user can change the Y value (right column) in the first input matrix, and that value is retained through the 2nd input matrix that is presented via modal dialog when the user clicks on the "Show 2nd input..." action button. All this works as intended.

The issue I have is retention of values input into that 2nd matrix. That matrix allows horizontal expansion (and deletion). That matrix works correctly in terms of auto-generated sequentially-numbered column headers, in groupings of 2. But if values are input into the additional columns (as shown in image at the bottom where columns "2" and "3" have been added for sake of example), and that modal dialog is closed and subsequently reopened, those added column values are not retained. They need to be retained. Note that user changes to column "1" are correctly retained. Any suggestions?

MWE code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)

yDflt <- 5

firstInput <- function(inputId,y,z){ # << y = y col default value, z = matrix row label
  matrixInput(inputId, 
              value = matrix(c(10,y), 1, 2, dimnames = list(c(z),c("X and Y",""))),
              rows =  list(extend = FALSE, names = TRUE),
              cols =  list(
                extend = FALSE, 
                names = TRUE, 
                editableNames = FALSE,
                multiheader=TRUE
              ),
              class = "numeric")}

secondInput <- function(inputId,y,z){ # << y = y col default value, z = matrix row label
  matrixInput(inputId, 
              value = matrix(c(10,y), 1, 2, dimnames = list(c(z),c(1,""))),
              label = "Add, delete, or modify matrix parameters:",
              rows =  list(extend = FALSE, names = TRUE),
              cols =  list(
                extend = TRUE,
                delta = 2,
                delete = TRUE,
                names = TRUE, 
                editableNames = FALSE,
                multiheader=TRUE
              ),
              class = "numeric")}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      uiOutput("panel"),
      actionButton("showSecond","Show 2nd input (modal)",width = "100%")
    ),
    mainPanel(plotOutput("plot1"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
 
  output$panel <- renderUI({firstInput("input1",yDflt,"1st input")})
  
  observeEvent(input$showSecond,{
    showModal(
      modalDialog(
        secondInput(
          "input2",
          if(isTruthy(input$input2)){input$input2[1,2]} else {input$input1[1,2]},
          "2nd input"),
        footer = modalButton("Close")
      ))
  })
  
  observe({ # << Assign sequential col header to matrix based on groupings of two
    req(input$input2)
    mm <- input$input2
    colnames(mm) <- trunc(1:ncol(mm)/2)+1 
    isolate(updateMatrixInput(session, "input2", mm))
  })
  
  output$secondInput <- renderUI({
    req(input$input1)
    secondInput("input2",input$input1[1,2],"2nd Input")
  })
  
  outputOptions(output,"secondInput",suspendWhenHidden = FALSE) 
  
  output$plot1 <-renderPlot({
    req(input$input1)
    plot(rep(if(isTruthy(input$input2)){input$input2[1,2]} else {input$input1[1,2]}, times=10))
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Image:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem with original MWE code posted is in the isTruthy test in the modal dialog (to see if the user has made an input into that modal dialog: `if(isTruthy(input$input2)){input$input2[1,2]} else {input$input1[1,2]},...`), the `else` part of it was too narrowly defined, to just the "y" input of the matrix input (`else {input$input1[1,2]}...`). The solution broadens out the results of else compliance to all of input$input2 (input2 being the modal dialog inputs): `else {myInput("input2",input$input2,TRUE,2,TRUE)}`... Note that the below condenses the various `matrixInput` functions from original MWE into `myInput` custom function, shortening the code.

Revised MWE code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)

###################################################################################################
#  a = matrix to input into matrixInput            d = delta # of columns when extending columns  #
#  b = variable for y column of input matrix       e = user option to delete column               #
#  c = extend matrix columns (T/F)                                                                #
################################################################################################### 

# matValues... feed into matrixInput as initial matrix; b parameter is for initial "Y" value
  matValue1 <- function(b){matrix(c(10,b), 1, 2, dimnames = list(c("1st input"),c("X and Y","")))}
  matValue2 <- function(b){matrix(c(10,b), 1, 2, dimnames = list(c("2nd input"),c(1,"")))}

myInput <- function(inputId,a,c,d,e){ 
  matrixInput(inputId, 
              value = a,
              rows =  list(extend = FALSE, names = TRUE),
              cols =  list(extend = c, 
                           delta = d,
                           delete = e,
                           names = TRUE, 
                           editableNames = FALSE,
                           multiheader=TRUE),
              class = "numeric")}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      uiOutput("panel"),
      actionButton("showSecond","Show 2nd input (modal)",width = "100%")
    ),
    mainPanel(plotOutput("plot1"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
 
  output$panel <- renderUI({myInput("input1",matValue1(256),FALSE,1,FALSE)})
  
  observeEvent(input$showSecond,{
    showModal(
      modalDialog(
        if(is.null(input$input2))
          {myInput("input2",matValue2(input$input1[1,2]),TRUE,2,TRUE)}
            else {myInput("input2",input$input2,TRUE,2,TRUE)}, 
        footer = modalButton("Close")
      ))
  })
  
  observe({ # << Assign sequential col header to matrix based on groupings of two
    req(input$input2)
    mm <- input$input2
    colnames(mm) <- trunc(1:ncol(mm)/2)+1 
    isolate(updateMatrixInput(session, "input2", mm))
  })
  
  output$secondInput <- renderUI({
    req(input$input1)
    myInput("input2",matValue2(input$input1[1,2]),TRUE,2,TRUE)
  })
  
  outputOptions(output,"secondInput",suspendWhenHidden = FALSE) 
  
  output$plot1 <-renderPlot({
    req(input$input1)
    plot(rep(if(isTruthy(input$input2)){input$input2[1,2]} else {input$input1[1,2]}, times=10))
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```